# CSS3 Marquee using nth-child(1n+1)

Tags: css, animation, marquee

I'm working on putting a marquee onto my website and I found a web tutorial that would do exactly two items :

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/

I need this to work for as many items as there are in the .marquee class because I'm reading them in from a database.  it works great if i just have a p:nth-child(1), but i don't know how many children there will be at any given time.

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>
        <div class="marquee">
            <p>This is the first text.</p>
            <p>This is the second.</p>
            <p>Some other announcement here.</p>
            <p>Hello World.</p>
            <p>Something Here.</p>
            <p>Last Announcement.</p>
        </div>
    </p>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
.marquee {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 25px auto;
    background-color: #222;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
}
.marquee p {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);
}
.marquee p {
    transform:translateX(100%);
}
@keyframes left {
    0% {
        transform:translateX(100%);
    }
    10% {
        transform:translateX(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform:translateX(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform:translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform:translateX(-100%);
    }
}
.marquee p:nth-child(n) {
    animation: left 10s ease infinite;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/BethFNewbie/Lc6gct3f/

Comment: Before using marquees, be aware of [What are arguments against the usage of a ticker / marquee on websites?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/76951)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the item count as HTML attribute, for example as `class='marquee item-count-5'` and then assign the according keyframes to the child elements.

#### There is no clean solution using CSS only, because:

You can do this only through defining multiple @keyframe definitions, because using animation-delay and the same keyframes does not work as *you cannot create delays in between* the animations. This is my unfinished, because unsuccessful hack: http://codepen.io/franzskuffka/pen/XbzRBY